# Related Numpy array typcasting

Tags: numpy

I have the below python code:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, '3'])
print(a)
```

output:

```
['1' '2' '3']
```

My question is, why all elements are converted into strings?
I know that in numpy array, if the array consist of different elements it will be typecasted. But on what basis it will be typecasted?

Comment: You can do `np.array([1, 2, '3'], int)`

Comment: If you don't specify the dtype, `np.array` deduces a minimal common dtype.  That must be documented somewhere, but the basic order is `object, unicode string, bytestring, float(s), ints`.  If you aren't happy with that ranking, make the `dtype` explicit.  It will raise an error if the conversion isn't possible.  String to number conversion only works if the corresponding python functions, `int()` and `float()` work.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly well explained in the [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) documentation (highlighting is mine):

> numpy.array(object, **dtype=None**, *, copy=True, order='K', subok=False, ndmin=0, like=None)
>
> […]
>
> **dtype**: data-type, optional
>
> The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will be determined as the **minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence.**

An integer can always be converted to string, the other way around it not always possible (e.g., `a` cannot be converted to string).

This is the same if you mix floats and integers, the array will be casted as float.